# UtteranceProgressListener not working after onResume

Tags: android

When my app is first installed or opened after being destroyed, it works great.  If you back out of it and go back in, then the onStart in UtteranceProgressListener never fires after onInit in OnInitListner.  When I open the app after backing out, everything else seems to be working.  Log shows that onInit is called, but it never progresses to the onStart in the UtteranceProgressListener.  How can I make this work?

in my onCreate:

```
// Implement Text to speech feature
        tts = getTts();
        // set progress listener to the TTS engine
        tts.setOnUtteranceProgressListener(new UtteranceProgressListener() {

            @Override
            public void onStart(String utteranceId) {
                Log.d("LOOK AT ME!!!", "ttsUtteranceListener - onStart");

            }

            @Override
            public void onError(String utteranceId) {
                Log.d("LOOK AT ME!!!", "ttsUtteranceListener - onError");

            }

            @Override
            public void onDone(String utteranceId) {
                Log.d("LOOK AT ME!!!", "ttsUtteranceListener - onDone");
                if (processStarted) {
                    MainActivity.this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            Log.d("LOOK AT ME!!!",
                                    "ttsUtteranceListener - speech,startListening");
                            speech.startListening(intent);
                        }
                    });
                } else {
                    ...
                }

                processStarted = false;
            }
        });
```

and here is "getTts()":

```
private TextToSpeech getTts() {

if (tts == null) {
    // Implement Text to speech feature
    tts = new TextToSpeech(this, new OnInitListener() {

        @Override
        public void onInit(int status) {
            Log.d("LOOK AT ME!!!", "ttsInitListener - onInit");

            if (status == TextToSpeech.SUCCESS) {
                tts.setLanguage(Locale.getDefault());

            } else {
                tts = null;
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,
                        "Failed to initialize TTS engine.",
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
    });
}
return tts;
}
```

and here are my lifecycle calls (onPause and onResume) :

```
// --- LIFECYCLE ---

@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    Log.d("LOOK AT ME!!!", "onResume");

    if (tts == null) {
    tts = getTts();
    }
}

@Override
public void onPause() {

    // Stop then shut down the TextToSpeech Engine
    if (tts != null) {
        tts.stop();
        tts.shutdown();

        tts = null;
    }

    super.onPause();
}
```

Comment: Did you find any solution to this?